# VF/Apex to Open in New Window?

Tags: apex, visualforce, url

I've discovered that adding target="_blank" to some hyperlink code opens the window in a new tab. Is there a way we can get it to open a whole new window?

Here is an example of what we have right now

```
<p><apex:outputlink value="https:......" target="_blank">Name of URL</apex:outputlink></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) method:

```
window.open('some_URL');
```

It will open an URL in a new browser window. Use `onclick` behavior for that.

Example:

```
<apex:outputLink onclick="window.open('/apex/SomePage')">Click me!</apex:outputLink>
```

Or just using pure html:

```
<script>
function urlOpener(url){
    window.open(url);
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="urlOpener('/apex/SomePage');">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: Where would I put that in relation to the rest of the code?

Comment: @FeliciaAbramson Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The target attribute is a standard html attribute which was implemented in the output link component ( [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputLink.htm)). This renders out as the html attribute.

What then happens, depends on your browser's implementation. I do think the original meaning of `target="_blank"` was to open a new window, which most browsers have changed to opening a new tab when they evolved to a tabular interface. I'm not sure if there is any (new) standard that will result into a opening a new window.

If you do want a new window behavoir, I'd recommend you test any work-around specifically on the browsers you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
var newwindow = window.open("https://appronic-dev-ed--c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/demo1?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1", "_self", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");newwindow.focus();
```

Note: If it is help full for you then please make this answer as best answer.

Thanks